# Subsetting multidimensional array using matrix in R

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I have a 4 dimensional array of water temperatures [lon, lat, depth, month] and I want to extract monthly temperatures based on a matrix where the rows and columns are lon and lat respectively and the values the depth levels. The result would be a 3 dimensional array of monthly temperatures at variable depth [lon, lat, month].

Just to provide an example:

```
set.seed(1)    
temperature <- array(rnorm(10), rep(3,4))
depth <- matrix(c(NA, sample(1:3, 8, replace = TRUE)), 3, 3)
```

I had a look at [How to index a multidimensional R array dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514964/how-to-index-a-multidimensional-r-array-dynamically?rq=1) and [R use matrix to select row of multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795331/r-use-matrix-to-select-row-of-multidimensional-array?lq=1) but can't work out how to do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you deal with the `NA`? Which months you want to select? Please provide the expected output.

Comment: NAs are locations locations where no temperature data is available (land), so I don't want to do anything in those cases, only preserve them as NAs because that makes it easier to plot later on. I'd like to select all months, hence the 3d output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be way off, but that's a try:

```
#get the indices relative to lon, lat and depth
threeIndices<-cbind(c(row(depth)),c(col(depth)),c(depth))
#repeat each row of the above to host a different month value
threeIndices<-threeIndices[rep(1:nrow(threeIndices),dim(temperature)[4]),]
#define the month index
fourthIndex<-rep(1:dim(temperature)[4],each=nrow(threeIndices)/dim(temperature)[4])
#putting all together
allIndices<-cbind(threeIndices,fourthIndex)
#subsetting and putting in an array
array(temperature[allIndices],dim(temperature)[c(1,2,4)])
```

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I agree so much with you that if you make an answer just stating "arrays are seriously ugly", I will give you +1 and regret than couldn't vote more for it.

Comment: Just remove the code that doesn't appear to do what you want.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Done. I was awaiting for a feedback from the OP, since I was not sure which one was correct. Now by thinking about it I'm a little more confident that the first lines were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Nicola's answer helped a lot. I figured out a potentially quicker way without specifying each month individually based on the suggestion.

```
#get the indices relative to lon, lat and depth
threeIndices <- cbind(c(row(depth)),c(col(depth)),c(depth))
# subset and put back in array
temperature.depth <- array(apply(temperature, 4, `[`, threeIndices), dim = dim(temperature)[c(1,2,4)])
```